# docker "--volumes-from" files not updating to target containers

Tags: docker, mounted-volumes

There's a lot of discussion about Docker volumes, but the following doesn't seem to be addressed.

I have a simple container arrangement. I have one volume container that has configs. I have a second container that pulls those configs in using --volumes-from the first container. This all works fine, and I can launch multiple instances of the second container, and all of the files are mounted as expected.

```
docker run --name configs -d config_image
docker run -it --volumes-from configs --name app1 app_image
docker run -it --volumes-from configs --name app2 app_image
```

However, if the config files change in the configs volume (created by the Dockerfile), the "app" containers that have mounted this volume do not see the changes. I have to restart the app container to see the files. I have also tested writing to the volume, and this works, but changes by one container are not seen by the other (until it is restarted).

This seems to be working as advertised, just without a real time update. I read something about inode mounting, and that this may be a problem with mount in general.

Would anyone know if this is possible or can shed some light on what may be happening?

Thanks.